# Validate range between numbers with FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net, validation, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation to validate some fields, and there's one field I want to validate if it's between 2 numbers I set, but it's not working, using breakpoints it simply skips this step, looks like it's not validating at all.

PS: I tried `InclusiveBetween(min, max)` aswell, no success.

Any way to validate?

My last attempt:

```cs
    public override bool IsValid()
    {
      InlineValidator<CreateFunctionCommand> validator = new();

      validator.RuleFor(validateField => validateField.HourlyRate)
       .Must(HourlyRateValidation)
       .WithErrorCode(GlobalizationConstants.BASIC0001)
       .WithMessage(GlobalizationConstants.BASIC0001.Resource());


      return base.IsValid();
    }

    private bool HourlyRateValidation(int hourlyRate)
    {
      return hourlyRate >= 10 && hourlyRate <= 100;
    }
```

Comment: Just use LessThan/GreaterThan extensions instead of the Must.

Comment: Seems to be working as expected in the fiddle. https://dotnetfiddle.net/TleKFC. Without using `InlineValidator`

Comment: if `.InclusiveBetween(10, 100)` does not work then your Must won't work either, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I guess it's something about using `InlineValidator` then @RBee